# Maven and dependencies

Tags: maven

I have a simply POM like this :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sim</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.sim</groupId>
    <artifactId>sim-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../sim-java/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<name>log4j</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

I run `mvn clean package` on this project and a JAR is created as expected.

When I navigate into this JAR, I thought that I would see a JAR named log4j-1.2.17.jar inside it but it's not the case.

Using dependency with compile scope does not include JAR into packaging version of project ?

Thank you for clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jar:jar` plugin of maven just compiles your source and bundles it into a jar. Just like building a jar out of ant or bare hands, no dependency jars will be bundled in the jar. Jars cannot have dependent jars bundled inside them and even if they did, they cannot be loaded by the default class loader.

If you are looking to build a ejb-jar, then you might want to consider a [EJB plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/ejb-mojo.html)

Check [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html) link for various plugins that you can exploit.

Comment: Thank you it's seem that I have much lacunas with java...So, I will add log4j directly inside ear not inside jar.

Comment: Ouch. Did you say ear? Give the EAR plugin a look. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/

Comment: As always, if you need more control like your makefile in C, you could fall back for Ant http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html but maven is considered a cleaner approach.